# How to import a package within modules (maven)

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a mvn project which has sub-modules. 
In one of the modules "moduleC", there is a class present inside a package "com.C.cto.wi.cipher.ssl". I need to be able to use/call it from classes within moduleA.

Parent pom:

```
<groupId>parent_groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>parent_artifactId</artifactId>
<version>parent_version</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>parent_artifactId</name>

<modules>
    <module>moduleA</module>
    <module>moduleB</module>
</modules>
```

moduleB pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>parent_groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent_artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>parent_version</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>moduleB</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>moduleB</name>
<modules>
    <module>moduleC</module>
</modules>
```

Now, moduleC pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>parent_groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>moduleB</artifactId>
    <version>parent_version</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>moduleC</artifactId>    
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<name>moduleC</name>
<dependency>
// List of dependencies
</dependency>
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>                
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>SomeName</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>SomeName</Bundle-Name>
                        <Bundle-Activator>someActivator</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Import-Package>org.osgi.framework</Import-Package>
                        <Export-Package>com.C.cto.wi.cipher.ssl</Export-Package>
                        <Embed-Dependency>
                        </Embed-Dependency>
                        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>someName</finalName>
    </build>
```

Now, I have a class in module A which needs to access the classes present in the package "com.C.cto.wi.cipher.ssl".

What pom modifications would be required to acheive that?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you pom files are structured, but you must include moduleC as a dependency in moduleA.

Also, you have export the required package in moduleC-info.java:

```
exports com.C.cto.wi.cipher.ssl;
```

Finally, make sure you modify moduleA-info.java with:

```
requires moduleC;
```

Comment: I've edited the question with more details on how the poms are structured. In that case, how do I include moduleC as dependency in module A? Can you show me code-wise? Secondly, what are you referring to moduleA-info.java and moduleC-info.java?

Comment: I think there is an error in your update. You are defining Module B as its own parent. Another question, is there any specific reason why you are using maven-bundle-plugin?

Comment: If you are not familiar with module-info.java file I suggest you start with this simple tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-modularity or https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start. Finally, is there any specific reason why you are using maven-bundle-plugin?

Comment: I've fixed the update. I'm not sure why maven-bundle-plugin is used. It is a legacy project. I'm not 100% aware why this plugin is used.